# SQL loader when clause conditions to satisfy if a column is starting with certain four digits then skip the row

Tags: sql-loader

I am trying to create a SQL loader CTL file and required to ignore rows that are starting with specific number in a column. suppose a column record_id =1211.6540D then ignore the row if the record column value starts with 1211.

I tried with position of numbers but the columns values before the record_id are not constant.

Can you please help.

Comment: Can't we use the NOT LIKE operator here like record_id NOT LIKE '1211%'?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.The SQL loader is taking =,=!,<>  only for  WHEN . So i have used Case, when, then ,else in column derivation and  it worked.